# Microsoft Azure doesn't return email via Oauth2 flow

Tags: ruby, azure, jwt, azure-active-directory

I am making Oauth2 flow with ruby and Microsoft Azure Active Directory. Basically authentication works fine, except fact that when I decode token I do not receive email of user. Here is what I receive from Azure after authentication:

```
{
"token_type"=>"Bearer",
"scope"=>"profile openid email https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read",
"ext_expires_in"=>3599,
"id_token"=> id_token_here,
"access_token"=> access_token_here,
"refresh_token"=>nil,
"expires_at"=>1572529008
}
```

When I try to decode "id_token" via I receive this kind of object:

```
{
"aud"=>"fa792156-3c62...",
"iss"=>"https://login.microsoftonline.com/some_sensitive_data/v2.0",
"iat"=>1572525194,
"nbf"=>1572525194,
"exp"=>1572529094,
"sub"=>"1ML3cHqqyg_...",
"tid"=>"fa024876-4da...",
"uti"=>"wvSdJLUxI0W...",
"ver"=>"2.0"
}
```

So I do NOT have email or something like this. When I try to login with another account I do receive 'preferred_username' or 'email' keys. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both single tenant and multi tenant, also tried tenant user and guest user. But I didn't reproduce your issue. Here are my steps.

Use code auth flow to get the code:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=cbc32712-ac27-4532XXXd-303998a6e712
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&response_mode=query
&scope=profile openid email https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
&state=12345
```

Use the code to get id token

[image]

[image]

Decode the id token

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you for answer. I have rechecked again my settings. Seems I have messed up with email scope I guess, because on my personal account it returned email, but on company account it didn't send email back. Now it seems works fine. Thanks again!